# In Composite C1, should each client have their own instance?

Tags: content-management-system, c1-cms

I'm wondering if for Composite C1, if each site should have its own instance, or if the one backend interface can be configured to host multiple sites.

I noticed that using user permissions I can make one user see only their content, not another's.

What are the best practices with regards to this? For each client, deploy a fresh, separate instance of C1?

Answer (score 3):

In Composite C1, you can create more than one website. Each website has its own homepage (the root page of the website) and you can assign permissions on pages for both users and user groups.

For more information read these articles:

[URL configuration in C1](http://docs.composite.net/C1/Getting-started/Configuration/UrlConfiguration.aspx)

[Assign local permissions](http://users.composite.net/C1/Superuser/Security/LocalPermissions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the license. From recent contact with the makers of Composite I understand that 1 install can be used for 1 legal entity (client). Technically you can setup more then one website in Composite.

Comment: C1 is 100% open source and free to use in whatever way you want to use it.